# Source safe adding redundant parent folder

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

Why when I add a new solution to Source safe from visual studio does it add a redundant parent folder with the same name as my solution.  For example, if my solution is called Project X, when it is added to source safe it is now found in Project X > ProjectX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does.

IIRC this is a workaround for the lack of a project file with web site projects.

You can fix it by moving things in VSS and then editting your `user.ini` file to remove the extra folder mapping that will have been added.

(The real fix is to get a real source code control tool.)

Comment: Yeah I agree, though the client I'm currently working for insists on it.